# Kingswaysoft SSIS Issue Premium Derived Column failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, migration, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> Error at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint
>   [Premium Derived Column [362]]: The component is missing, not
>   registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The
>   contact information for this component is "KingswaySoft Inc.;
>   http://www.kingswaysoft.com; support@kingswaysoft.com; Copyright
>   2011-2017 KingswaySoft Inc.".
>
> Error at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint
>   [SSIS.Pipeline]: Premium Derived Column failed validation and returned
>   error code 0xC0048021.
>
> Error at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint
>   [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint:
>   There were errors during task validation.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Comment: Sounds like an installation or licensing problem for your KingswaySoft add on. I would contact support.

Comment: Jacob is right.Please make sure to have the SSIS Productivity Pack installed. It is a separate download from the Dynamics 365 toolkit.

Comment: I have resolved that licensing issue but not I got another error.

Comment: Error: 0xC02090F9 at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint, Dynamics CRM Destination [90]: The Dynamics CRM Destination was unable to process the data.

Comment: Error: 0xC0047022 at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Dynamics CRM Destination" (90) failed with error code 0xC02090F9 while processing input "Input" (108). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an installation issue. Please make sure to have the [SSIS Productivity Pack](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/download) installed. It is a separate download from the Dynamics 365 toolkit. Once you have the software installed, you should be good to go.

Comment: Error: 0xC02090F9 at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint, Dynamics CRM Destination [90]: The Dynamics CRM Destination was unable to process the data.

Comment: Error: 0xC0047022 at Migrate Documents from Dynamics 365 Notes to SharePoint, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Dynamics CRM Destination" (90) failed with error code 0xC02090F9 while processing input "Input" (108). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: There should be another line of error which you should post here.